# google calendar watch notification getting nul

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Hi have setup watch on google calendar

```
$channelID = "my-caledar-".  date('His',  time()); 
$channel->setId($channelID);
$channel->setType('web_hook');
$channel->setAddress('xxxxx');
```

and getting valid params after call this method

and when I create/delete any event on calendar , I am getting null on push notification url

```
if($_POST){
$msg = json_encode($_POST);
pg_query($pg_conn, "INSERT INTO postdata(post_data) values ('$msg')");
} else {
  $result = pg_query($pg_conn, "SELECT * FROM postdata;");
}
```

$result getting empty filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifiction not comes on url as a **POST params** , We can get it via $_SERVER variable like this

```
$msg = json_encode(array('HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID' =>  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID'],
'HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_EXPIRATION' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_EXPIRATION'],
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_STATE' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_STATE'],
'HTTP_X_GOOG_MESSAGE_NUMBER' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_MESSAGE_NUMBER'],
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID'],
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_URI' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_URI']
));
```